# How to handle large string coming as an input parameter to the procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am getting 200 Supplier names as an input parameter with huge values to the stored procedure.I tried declaring in CLOB,VARCHAR2(32767).But when i try to execute it is not accepting.
Please anyone help me how to handle this   .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GMMT_PROC.or_rmce_RB_grid_sp (
   p_plant_cd        IN VARCHAR2,
   p_region_cd       IN VARCHAR2,
   p_matrl_nbr       IN OUT VARCHAR2,
   p_supplier_nbr    IN OUT VARCHAR2,
   p_supplier_name   IN OUT CLOB,
   p_mrpcontrollercd IN OUT VARCHAR2,
   p_currency        IN   VARCHAR2,
   oresultset        OUT  sys_refcursor,
   p_err_cd          OUT  NUMBER,
   p_err_msg         OUT  VARCHAR2
)
IS
sqlquery varchar2(10000);
p1 varchar2(10);
p2 varchar2(20);
p3 varchar2(20);
p4 varchar2(20);
v_percent varchar2(10):='%';
V_FROM_CURRENCY VARCHAR2(5);
V_EX_RATE NUMBER;
v_matrl_nbr       VARCHAR2(10000);
v_supplier_nbr    VARCHAR2(10000);
v_supplier_name   CLOB;
v_mrpcontrollercd  VARCHAR2(10000);

BEGIN
p1:='matrl_nbr';
 v_matrl_nbr:=p_matrl_nbr;
 p2:='supplier_nbr';
 v_supplier_nbr :=p_supplier_nbr;
 p3:='supplier_name_txt';
 v_supplier_name :=p_supplier_name;
 p4:='mrp_controller_cd';
 v_mrpcontrollercd:=p_mrpcontrollercd; 
sqlquery:='select wk_nbr, nbr_working_days,'||p1||' as matrl_nbr ,'||p2||' as supplier_nbr,'||p3||' as supplier_name_txt,'||p4||' as mrp_controller_cd,sum(reqmnt_qty)reqmnt_qty , sum(proj_inven_qty)proj_inven_qty, sum(doh) doh,sum(proj_recpt_1) proj_recpt_1, sum(proj_recpt_2) proj_recpt_2, sum(proj_recpt_3) proj_recpt_3, sum(proj_recpt_4) proj_recpt_4,sum( proj_recpt_total_qty) proj_recpt_total_qty,sum(consumption_qty) consumption_qty, sum(consumption_var_qty) consumption_var_qty , sum(final_recpt_qty) final_recpt_qty,sum(recpt_var_qty) recpt_var_qty from GMMT_OWNER.OR_RMCE_GTT_PROJ_RECPT_T ';
sqlquery:=sqlquery||' where ('''||v_matrl_nbr||''' IS NULL) OR matrl_nbr IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(GMMT_PROC.OR_in_list_RPT5_FN('''||v_matrl_nbr||'''))) OR matrl_nbr like '''|| v_matrl_nbr||v_percent||'''';
sqlquery:=sqlquery||' AND ('''||v_supplier_nbr||''' IS NULL) OR supplier_nbr IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(GMMT_PROC.OR_in_list_RPT5_FN('''||v_supplier_nbr||'''))) OR supplier_nbr like '''|| v_supplier_nbr||v_percent||'''';
sqlquery:=sqlquery||' AND ('''||v_supplier_name||''' IS NULL) OR supplier_name_txt IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(GMMT_PROC.OR_in_list_RPT5_FN('''||v_supplier_name||'''))) OR supplier_name_txt like '''|| v_supplier_name||v_percent||'''';
sqlquery:=sqlquery||' AND ('''||v_mrpcontrollercd||''' IS NULL) OR mrp_controller_cd IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(GMMT_PROC.OR_in_list_RPT5_FN('''||v_mrpcontrollercd||'''))) OR mrp_controller_cd like '''|| v_mrpcontrollercd||v_percent||'''';
sqlquery:=sqlquery||' group by wk_nbr, nbr_working_days,'||p1||','||p2||','||p3||','||p4||' order by wk_nbr';

OPEN oresultset FOR sqlquery;

dbms_output.put_line(sqlquery);
END;
```

Comment: declaring CLOB should work, what error you are getting

Comment: I am trying to print the supplier names which is getting as an input parameters.I am getting statement handle not executed.

Comment: Post code and error message (the CLOB version)

Comment: @mani.gkn Please update your question

Comment: -1: Please don't edit your code here: just copy and paste it directly from your real environment.

Comment: What is your question exactly? What error message do you get?

Comment: There is a supplier name user parameter it is very big in length.So it is giving me error when i execute this . ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-01003: no statement parsed. I know its because of length but i dont know where to modify.Pls help me

Comment: There I got a different error. Now new error after i make sqlquery variable as CLOB. Then i get a different error.

Comment: Also why do you use dynamic SQL when straight SQL would work a lot better with a lot less code?

Comment: Dynamic sql I am using because the user might not pass all the parameters at a time .So based on the user param i Need to fetch from table and group by.

Comment: In the other question I instructed you to use bind variables. You haven't done that.

Comment: @mani.gkn Okay, p1...p4 are column names but **all other are variables** and should not be glued into your SQL, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about bind variables! Never, *ever* concatenate values passed into a SQL statement.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10472/dynamic.htm#CHDFCHHJ for why this is a bad idea.

Now the problem you are having is caused by the large value being inserted into the SQL statement, making a *very* long string -- too long for a varchar.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10472/dynamic.htm#BJEDAHEE for how to use bind variables with dynamic SQL from PL/SQL.

Comment: Hi Can u please tell me how to solve this.After i increase the size of Sqlquery it is giving ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01003: no statement parsed..I din knw other option than this so i usd this. Can u tell me what i can do for this

Comment: Read the last link of my answer! It describes how to use bind variables which will solve all of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SQL: don't do it like this.

You should never, never ever concatenate a variable containing a value to SQL. [Never, please](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:104931400346587790) it kills performance, produce hard to reproduce/find bugs and is blatantly open to SQL injection.

It is okay to use dynamic SQL for dynamic grouping because P1... P4 aren't values but are column names and as such can't be bound.

[**ALL other variables should be passed as binds**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#BJEDAHEE):

your OPEN statement should be:

```
OPEN oresultset FOR '
SELECT wk_nbr,
       nbr_working_days,
       ' || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(p1) || ' AS matrl_nbr,
       ' || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(p2) || ' AS supplier_nbr,
       ' || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(p3) || ' AS supplier_name_txt,
       ' || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(p4) || ' AS mrp_controller_cd,
       sum(reqmnt_qty) reqmnt_qty,
       [...]
  FROM GMMT_OWNER.OR_RMCE_GTT_PROJ_RECPT_T
 WHERE (:VAR1 IS NULL)
    OR matrl_nbr IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(GMMT_PROC.OR_in_list_RPT5_FN(:VAR1)))
    OR matrl_nbr LIKE :VAR1 || ''%''
    AND (:VAR2 IS NULL)
    OR supplier_nbr IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(GMMT_PROC.OR_in_list_RPT5_FN(:VAR2)))
    OR supplier_nbr LIKE :VAR2 || ''%''
    [...]
GROUP BY wk_nbr,
         nbr_working_days,
         ' || p1 || ', ' || p2 || ', ' || p3 || ', ' || p4 || '
ORDER BY wk_nbr' 
   USING v_matrl_nbr, v_matrl_nbr, v_matrl_nbr, 
         v_supplier_nbr, v_supplier_nbr, v_supplier_nbr,
         [...];
```

To prevent users from abusing this dynamic SQL piece, you have to make sure that p1...p4 are pre-approved from a list defined by you or use [DBMS_ASSERT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_assert.htm#BABHIEBA) as above.

In practice if the list is small, you could use simple static SQL:

```
OPEN cc FOR 
    SELECT wk_nbr,
           nbr_working_days,
           decode(p1, 'column1', column1, 'column2', column2 [...]) AS matrl_nbr,
           [...]
     GROUP BY [...]
              decode(p1, 'column1', column1, 'column2', column2 [...]),
              [...];
```